# Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes when serverless deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: MainLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 77d73bfc-51e1-490a-98b4-fdf8066d225b)" (RequestToken: 98920b07-72f7-ca3d-ec22-e49a5de4101a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

i tried to deploy the lambda with docker i faced another problem

[image: Error when dockerizing the lambda]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to deploy a Lambda function that is using a layer that is too large. The maximum size for a layer is 250 MB.

Comment: There is a hard limit on the size of the lambda - why are your layers so huge?

Comment: @luk2302 , i need to use all the layers

Comment: What is the question here? "i faced another problem" is a nice cliffhanger but nothing actionable...

Comment: Evidently you cannot use all the layers because they are too large. I repeat my question: why are they so large?

Comment: @Maurice , i just added a picture describing the problem when i tried to dockerize

Comment: @luk2302 , because they contains many modules for example : numpy , scipy  , scikit-learn , pillow , PyNaCl  , ....

Comment: What is your question here? Those dependencies are too large for zip + layer based Lambdas so you need an image-based Lambda. For that, you've provided no debugging details (Dockerfile, tooling, configs, ...). That screenshot should have been a text copy paste, it's barely readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Dockerized the whole lambda , i had a problem in the Dockerfile + serverless.yml in the previous version that's why i faced that problem in the screenshot, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda function is running within VPC, a better way would be to use EFS feature with Lambda where EFS can help you deploying large code packages

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

If outside of VPC, go for lambda container image, this will support 10 GB

Comment: thanks !  ,   i'm gonna try this solution and i'll let you know